# Why does my phone get stuck "Searching..." and requires a DFU reset?

Tags: iphone, network, cellular-data, sim, cellular-carriers

I have an Iphone 8 plus, very well looked after, and about 3 months ago i changed my carrier.

Two weeks ago, my phone "failed to activate mobile network" a few times, and i restarted it, which put it in some weird mode where everything was working fine, but it was stuck "Searching..." for the mobile network.

I went to their branch and after reseting my phone settings to factory default and failing to fix it, they suggested I put it in DFU mode and reset it because the firmware has somehow been corrupted. 
A painstaking 6 hours of backing up, resetting, troubleshooting, and restoring later the phone was working once again, connecting to the network just fine.

Fast forward to today, and my phone loses reception for a couple of seconds, finds it again going into "EDGE", and then switches to 3G as i moved but fails to activate network in the very same place  I restart it, and it is stuck searching once again... Exactly the same sequence of events as last time...

I have tried:

1. Hard-resetting
2. Resetting network settings
3. Turning off, Putting in an old inactive SIM, turning back on (no change whatsoever)
4. Putting my current SIM to an old phone (works like a charm)

Any ideas on what could be going wrong and how to fix it once and for all?

**Update #1**: Contacted the provider (VOXI) and they told me it is a "known problem with IPhones" and that "They can't do anything about it"...

Comment: If it was a "know problem with iPhones" then you'd be seeing that problem all over this, and other, Apple boards.  It might be a problem at times but I don't think it's widespread.  I get the feeling they just don't want to deal with it.

Comment: I had a very similar issue a couple of years ago - it was fixed by my carrier sending me a more up to date SIM. SIM firmware changes over the years. If your carrier can't keep up with the technology in the world's most popular mobile device, then it might be time to find another carrier. Their excuse is the most pathetic I've ever heard.

Comment: I would bet they left out a crucial part of their answer, "...known problem with iPhones, **on our network.**

Comment: I was disappointed(as this is not relatable) after I read the post when I came here due to the catchy title.

Comment: @fsb Thats very true. I said that and the response was "If it was our problem we would have fixed it" :/

Comment: @Tetsujin I will go get a new sim tomorrow morning, but ive only had this one for arround 3 months! I hope its just 'faulty' in some weird way

Comment: @SteveChambers Haha, very true. I was with a different provider before for 3 years and have never had any problems due to "iphones" accross my two IPhone devices on that network... Its just a more expensive provider :/

Comment: @ankii Appologies, I have now made the title more specific!